# Interpret the output of smartctl for SSD and hard drive

Tags: hard-disk, ssd, smartctl, failure-resistance

I have dropped my external hard drive on the floor recently and wanted to know if the electronic parts and mechanical parts were damaged. I have no idea how to find this out from the output of smartctl. While being on it, I also want to test my internal SSD. I ran `sudo smartctl -t short` for my internal SSD and my external hard drive. I searched the web, but find mostly values that are not available for me and little or no information on what values of mine are important and what they mean.

*Question:* What are the important values, how do I interpret those, what is the conclusion for each my SSD and my hard drive?

I read that the values are normalized to 100 (0 = worst, 100 = best). If I consider this, for the SSD, the temperature has a low value; for the hard drive, the Load_Cycle_Count and the Free_Fall_Sensor. But I am not sure if those are really concerning.

Btw, I make backups of both, but not super frequently, so I want to assess the situation.

### Output for SSD

```
:~$ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sdb
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-162-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33614         -
# 2  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     33260         -
# 3  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31886         -
# 4  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31862         -
# 5  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31843         -
# 6  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31808         -
# 7  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31781         -
# 8  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31724         -
# 9  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30974         -
#10  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30956         -
#11  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30916         -
#12  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30865         -
#13  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30733         -
#14  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30411         -
#15  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30189         -
#16  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30123         -
#17  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     27003         -
#18  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     26994         -
#19  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     23682         -
#20  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     23672         -
#21  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     23660         -

:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb         
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-162-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron BX/MX1/2/3/500, M5/600, 1100 SSDs
Device Model:     Crucial_CT240M500SSD3
Serial Number:    132609426436
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 109426436
Firmware Version: MU02
User Capacity:    240.057.409.536 bytes [240 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Mon Oct  2 21:12:28 2023 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                ( 1115) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  18) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x0035) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       17
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       16384
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       33614
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       4646
170 Reserved_Block_Count    0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       17
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   078   078   ---    Old_age   Always       -       667
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       252
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2701544260062
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       8985
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   053   001   ---    Old_age   Always       -       47 (0 99 255 128 0)
195 Cumulativ_Corrected_ECC 0x003a   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       4294967295
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       17
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain 0x0031   078   078   ---    Pre-fail  Offline      -       22
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     33614         -
# 2  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     33260         -
# 3  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31886         -
# 4  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31862         -
# 5  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31843         -
# 6  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31808         -
# 7  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31781         -
# 8  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     31724         -
# 9  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30974         -
#10  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30956         -
#11  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30916         -
#12  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30865         -
#13  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30733         -
#14  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30411         -
#15  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30189         -
#16  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     30123         -
#17  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     27003         -
#18  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     26994         -
#19  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     23682         -
#20  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     23672         -
#21  Vendor (0xff)       Completed without error       00%     23660         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

### Output for hard drive

```
:~$ sudo smartctl -l selftest /dev/sde
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-162-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     42184         -


:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sde
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.4.0-162-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Momentus 7200.4
Device Model:     ST9500420ASG
Serial Number:    5VJ7V4QE
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 02a611c46
Firmware Version: 0002SDM1
User Capacity:    500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Mon Oct  2 21:09:06 2023 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x73) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        No Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        ( 109) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x103f) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   104   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       156006002
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   098   085    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   093   093   020    Old_age   Always       -       7472
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       6
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   069   057   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       34427616775
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   052   052   000    Old_age   Always       -       42184
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   095   095   020    Old_age   Always       -       5753
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       12
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4295032844
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   063   045   045    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 37 (Min/Max 23/37)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3793
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       448328
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   037   055   000    Old_age   Always       -       37 (243 52 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   044   040   000    Old_age   Always       -       156006002
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       28989 (89 232 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       3926827122
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2382261124
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       8

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     42184         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Repost here: superuser.com

This question is not about Linux/Unix.